# How to Align two images inline in css

Tags: css, alignment

I have two images in a div and I want to align both of the images horizontally center in the div. I have tried but I am not able to get it, can any one help?

Thanks in advance, CSS code and image is attached:

```
div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.subscribeLogo {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

[image]

Comment: call image one div float right  image two div float left and call padding left and right in both side

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below;

test -> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLOeZR

**html**

```
<div>
  <img src="https://cdn3.droom.in/photos/images/drm/super-cars.png" width="100">
  <img src="https://cdn3.droom.in/photos/images/drm/super-cars.png" width="100">
</div>
```

**css**

```
div{
  width:500px;
  background-color:yellow;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using flex

plunker demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/ni0Z7NGNPDxYzgxBTuOd?p=preview

```css
.box {
  width: 500px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    lorem ispsium
    <br> <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="image-container">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x100" />
      </a>
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x100" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```